# Flutter: Horizontal Stepper - auto scrolling

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

As you may know, the `Stepper` widget puts step items into a row until it overflows the screen, with no way to make it scroll.
However, I found a way found in this link - https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/40601

Here is the code:

```
Widget _buildHorizontal() {
final List children = [
for (int i = 0; i < widget.steps.length; i += 1) ...[
InkResponse(
onTap: widget.steps[i].state != StepState.disabled
? () {
if (widget.onStepTapped != null) widget.onStepTapped(i);
}
: null,
canRequestFocus: widget.steps[i].state != StepState.disabled,
child: Row(
children: [
Container(
height: 72.0,
child: Center(
child: _buildIcon(i),
),
),
Container(
margin: const EdgeInsetsDirectional.only(start: 12.0),
child: _buildHeaderText(i),
),
],
),
),
if (!_isLast(i))
Container(
margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
height: 1.0,
color: Colors.grey.shade400,
),
],
];

return Column(
  children: <Widget>[
    Material(
      elevation: 2.0,
      child: Container(
        height: 65,
        margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24.0),
        child: ListView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          children: children,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(24.0),
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedSize(
            curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
            duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
            vsync: this,
            child: widget.steps[widget.currentStep].content,
          ),
          _buildVerticalControls(),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
);

}`
```

My issue right now is that I cannot make the `ListView` autoscrollable.
I have tried to use `_scrollController = ItemScrollController` but did not help.